# Can't get background to stay put

Tags: css, background-image, background-size

So what I want is for the background image to stay where it is (and not change size according to the amount of content), and for the left column to scroll and (if possible!) the right column to stay put.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite);

/*font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;*/

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico);

/*font-family:'Pacifico', cursive;*/

body {
  height: 100%;
}
#background {
  background-image: url('http://hd4desktop.com/images/b/1920x1080_pathway_in_forest-1211697.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
ul {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #7A4909;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 1em;
  font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
}
li a {
  color: #D0903C;
  background-color: #7A4909;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.left a:hover {
  color: #7A4909;
  background-color: #D0903C;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(1.2);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.right a:hover {
  color: #7A4909;
  background-color: #D0903C;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.2);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#wrap {
  width: 900px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-top: 90px;
}
#content {
  width: 700px;
  background-color: #D09B54;
  float: left;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
#sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #D0903C;
}
#sidebar ul li {
  font-size: 20px;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}
p {
  font-family: 'Dawning of a New Day', cursive;
}
```

```html
<body id="background">
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li class="left"><a href="home.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="right"><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
    </li>
    <li class="left"><a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li class="right"><a href="funny.html">Funny</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="content">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum!</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
        sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore
        eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
        euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate
        velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis
        eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim
        ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.
        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
        et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
        At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat. Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed
        diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
        ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
      </p>
    </div>
    <!--end content div-->
    <div id="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--end sidebar div-->
```

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/kc6e5yhx/

Comment: Well the sidebar is staying, so that's good, but I want the background to fill the page and not expand when more content is added. Additionally, I want the left column to scroll on its own-I don't want the background to scroll with it.

Comment: Check the updated fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/kc6e5yhx/2/

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out on my own eventually...
I removed the background's height and width and added background attachment:fixed.
In order to get my right column to stay put I used #sidebar ul {position:fixed;} but it wasn't the right width anymore so I had to assign a width of 200px to it again.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite);

/*font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;*/

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico);

/*font-family:'Pacifico', cursive;*/

body {
  height: 100%;
}
#background {
  background-image: url('http://hd4desktop.com/images/b/1920x1080_pathway_in_forest-1211697.jpg');
  background-position: center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  **background-attachment:fixed;**
}
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
ul {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #7A4909;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 1em;
  font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
}
li a {
  color: #D0903C;
  background-color: #7A4909;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.left a:hover {
  color: #7A4909;
  background-color: #D0903C;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(1.2);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.right a:hover {
  color: #7A4909;
  background-color: #D0903C;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.2);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#wrap {
  width: 900px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-top: 90px;
}
#content {
  width: 700px;
  background-color: #D09B54;
  float: left;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
#sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #D0903C;
}
**#sidebar ul {
  position:fixed;
  width:200px;
}**
#sidebar ul li {
  font-size: 20px;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}
p {
  font-family: 'Dawning of a New Day', cursive;
}
```

```html
<body id="background">
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li class="left"><a href="home.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="right"><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
    </li>
    <li class="left"><a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li class="right"><a href="funny.html">Funny</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="content">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum!</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
        sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore
        eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
        euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate
        velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis
        eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim
        ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.
        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
        et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
        At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat. Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed
        diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
        ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
      </p>
    </div>
    <!--end content div-->
    <div id="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--end sidebar div-->
```